# how to "kill" or cancel setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How can I "kill" this setTimout function but not to break my code?
I tried with clear and it didn't work.

For some reason when I delete it everywhere it breaks my code (also if i remove this function evertwhere).
When I say "return" on the top before timeout executes my jQuery shows up but my code doesn't work.

To mention also my jQuery file loads in Mozilla. It also loads on my local machine in Chrome and Safari, but not in live on the server( im also using Wordpress) Safari/Chrome.

Function with the setTimeout

```
function queueRender() {
    var _this = this;

    settings.queueRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        render();
    }, settings.debounce);
    if(typeof settings.queueRenderTimeout !== "undefined") {
        clearTimeout(settings.queueRenderTimeout)
    }
    render();
}
```

Here is render function

```
function render() {
    element.find(">").remove();
    var t = templates.quiz(quiz);
    element.append(t);

    $(settings.append).append(element);

}
```

-- so in this case, my jQuery loads, but my quiz breaks. 
if i change the order and put first IF statement then my code doesnt break.

Here is my settings:

```
    var defaults = {
        append: "body",
        quiz_template: "#quiz_template",
        question_template: "#question_template",
        answer_template: "#answer_template",
        result_template: "#result_template",
        shuffle: true
//      debounce: 10
    }
```

Code is something working sometimes don't. It works on my local machine, but  not on the server. I feel like there is still some delay from the setTimout even when I leave it "undefined".

Comment: You are clearing the timeout before settings it!

Comment: @unlucky13 Tried swapping them up -- didn't work. :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but, yes, after setting a timeout the `typeof settings.queueRenderTimeout !== "undefined"` is always true, as `settings.queueRenderTimeout` is now a timeout id.

Comment: @unlucky13 Ah yes! I forgot to put render() as last. Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome! Just a note, I think there is something in your code that doesn't make sense: you set a timeout and immediately clear it for no specific reason?

Comment: @unlucky13 actually this is a common debounce pattern

Comment: @charlietfl I don't consider it a debounce pattern. It's not implemented correctly.

Comment: what does *"when I delete it everywhere"* actually mean?

Comment: @charlietfl Like if i delete the function and delete it everywhere where the function is called everything stops working. But it shouldn't do that.

It actually loads my jQuery now, but breaks the quiz. Any other idea on how to correct this?

Comment: so what errors are thrown? create a demo that reproduces problem. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl made some changes in my post. Can you look at the code again, and tell me if i can have twice return?
I made a codepen, but it's not displaying. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpArGj -- you can see a quiz code starting on line 13 in JS section...

Comment: @unlucky13 
it checks my settings.debounce if I have it as defined. But since it's undefined it should render(). Anyway, when I swapped the functions it worked for a couple minutes and then again when I refreshed went back the same. Not sure how to get rid of that delay!